# SUMming Distinct Instances of Time Value with Two Criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm dying here and could really use some help. I've been slogging away at this for a day or two now and don't know what to try next.

In Excel, I have a list of technicians, dates and total hours worked by that tech on the corresponding day. There are duplicate entries which I cannot remove due to other unique values in the data.

I need to count up the total hours worked for each technician over the whole period. For example, in the instance below, Bob has worked eight hours, while Jim has worked six.

```
                   TOTAL
TECH   DATE      DAILY HOURS
----------------------------
Bob    01/03/21    03:00
Bob    01/03/21    03:00
Bob    01/03/21    03:00
Bob    02/03/21    02:00
Bob    03/03/21    03:00
Jim    01/03/21    03:00
Jim    02/03/21    02:00
Jim    02/03/21    02:00
Jim    02/03/21    02:00
Jim    02/03/21    02:00
Jim    03/03/21    01:00
```

I'm certain this should be relatively straightforward but I think I've reached the end of my knowledge. I've been struggling with `SUMPRODUCT` etc. and searched extensively online, but I'm beginning to get rather lost.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: What version of Excel have you got?

Comment: Depending on your version of Excel, you can do this easily with Power Query or (if Office 365) with formulas.

Comment: I have Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back and came up with a fairly crude solution as follows:

- in a new column (which I hid afterwards) create a function to return TRUE on the first instance of each unique combination to check (where 'combination' could be 'Bob on 01/03' or 'Jim on 03/03')
- Then for your overall totals do a `SUMIF` based only on those values returned by that auxiliary column.

In your example this might look like this:

- your auxiliary column is Z. the above columns are A, B and C. Row 1 contains headings.
- In Z2 you insert the formula `=IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A2, $A2, $B$2:$B2, $B2) = 0, TRUE, "")` then copy/autofill that downwards for as far as necessary. Check the result, it should be returning `TRUE` on the first entry per technician per day.
- Then, if somewhere else on your sheet you need a sum of what Bob did, you do `=SUMIFS($C:$C, $A:$A, "Bob", $Z:$Z, TRUE)` - that is, sum of all times where technician is bob and the auxiliary column is true.